# thumbnail photo selector with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create something like the screenshot below.  The big image on top will be the main display, and when you click on bottom thumbnails the big image on top will change to the thumbnail image.

ps ignore the "back to the top" text.

is there an easy way to do this with javascipt/jquery?

[image]

Comment: And what HTML mark-up are you using? What's the relationship between the two images (how does the script know what the URL of the large image is, when someone clicks on the thumbnail image)?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to accomplish this. The simplest way is to use one image like so:

```
<img src="myimg.jpg" class="thumb" title="Click Me" />

<div id="view"><img /></div>
```

With some JS/jQuery to do the following:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.thumb', swapImage); //wire up click event
});

function swapImage() { 
    var thumb = $(this);
    //steal src from thumb and pop it into main img
    $('#view').find('img').attr('src', thumb.attr('src'));
}
```

Make sure that you put some CSS on your thumbnail to scale it down, but let the `#view` image be full size. Of course this isn't the *best* way to do it, but it is one way that should point you in the correct direction.

A second way would be to create two images, one for your thumbnail and another for your main image. If you adhere to a strict naming convention, you could use the code above, but do something in the `swapImage()` function like:

```
    //thumb and large image are named the same, 
    //except large has "large-" in front
    $('#view').find('img').attr('src', 'large-' + thumb.attr('src'));
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to experiment a bit with Javascript Libraries, you can take a look at this

http://www.infoq.com/articles/emberjs

This is a sample application that could meet most of your requirements (in your question). There is sample working code that you should be able to customize.